# tikz node with listing environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, highlighting, tcolorbox

I'm trying to create a c++ class hierarchy. Each node in the hierarchy is a class description  with code listing in it and multiple nodes are connected by lines and arrows depicting the hierarchy. I'm trying to create the node using `tcolorbox` with code listing in it and encompass the box in `tikz node` so that I can draw lines between nodes.

So I created CodeNode environment, and trying to call `node` related stuff in the environment. The MWE is here

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}


\NewEnviron{CodeNode}{
  \node{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
      \begin{tcbwritetemp}
        {\BODY}
      \end{tcbwritetemp}
      \tcbox[arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,
             boxrule=0.6pt,title=#1]{\tcbusetemplisting}
    \end{minipage}
  };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tcolorbox}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{CodeNode}[class name]
       virtual void draw() = 0;
       virtual void some_other_function() = 0;
     \end{CodeNode}
   \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting error in tcbwritetemp

```
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '2.60'
)) (./mwe.aux) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! Argument of \next has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.30      \end{CodeNode}
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried loading `tcolorbox` with option `all`: `\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}` and compile the file with `-shell-escape`?

Comment: I did. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main problem seems to be the capture of the verbatim text in interaction with `tikz` and `environ`.

My solution proposal skips the `environ` package, which is a great tool, but is not needed here. The `CodeNode` options are saved by `mynodeoptions` and `mytcboptions`. I've added mandatory parameters like node name and position to the options. You can easily adapt my given example settings to your own needs.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newenvironment{CodeNode}[4][]{
  \tikzset{mynodeoptions/.style={at={(#2)},name=#3,#1}}%
  \tcbset{mytcboptions/.style={title=#4}}%
  \tcboutputlisting%
}{\endtcboutputlisting%
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none,mynodeoptions]{%
    \tcbinputlisting{listing only,width=0.8\textwidth,colback=white,
      arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,
      boxrule=0.6pt,mytcboptions}};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}[center upper,colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!5!white]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{CodeNode}{0,2}{anode}{class name}
virtual void draw() = 0;
virtual void some_other_function() = 0;
  \end{CodeNode}
  \begin{CodeNode}{0,-2}{bnode}{other class name}
virtual void other_draw() = 0;
virtual void yet_some_other_function() = 0;
  \end{CodeNode}
  \draw[red,very thick,->] (anode)--(bnode);
  \draw[red,very thick,->] (anode.east)-- ++(1,0);
  \draw[red,very thick,->] (anode.west)-- ++(-1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine. But I've one more request, this is about tcolorbox. The tcbinputlisting is, if i'm correct, based on `tcolorbox` and not `tcbox` (which shrink fits the contents). To make the listing box shrink fit, I'm using `/tcb/width` option, but this is not accurate. I do not find any macro for listing box based on `tcbox`. Is one available ?

Comment: Got it. It is `/tcb/capture=hbox`

Comment: @Surya Yes, exactly :-)